# Calculating Geometric median of 2D points

Tags: java, median

I am calculating [Geometric median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) of some `(x,y)` points in java. To calculate `Geometric median`, first i am calculating `centroid` of all the points, then this `centroid` is used to calculate `Geometric median`. My code works fine, but sometimes it goes to an infinite loop (i think.). The problem is with my `while` condition. This `while` condition should be change according to input points, but i don't know how. Below I am putting the complete code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GeometricMedian {

    private static ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    private class Point {
        private double x;
        private double y;

        Point(double a, double b) {
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeometricMedian gm = new GeometricMedian();
        gm.addPoints();
        Point centroid = gm.getCentroid();
        Point geoMedian = gm.getGeoMedian(centroid);
        System.out.println("GeometricMedian= {" + (float) geoMedian.x + ", "
                + (float) geoMedian.y + "}");
    }

    public void addPoints() {
        points.add(new Point(0, 1));
        points.add(new Point(2, 5));
        points.add(new Point(3, 1));
        points.add(new Point(4, 0));
    }

    public Point getCentroid() {
        double cx = 0.0D;
        double cy = 0.0D;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            Point pt = points.get(i);
            cx += pt.x;
            cy += pt.y;
        }
        return new Point(cx / points.size(), cy / points.size());
    }

    public Point getGeoMedian(Point start) {
        double cx = 0;
        double cy = 0;

        double centroidx = start.x;
        double centroidy = start.y;
        do {
            double totalWeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                Point pt = points.get(i);
                double weight = 1 / distance(pt.x, pt.y, centroidx, centroidy);
                cx += pt.x * weight;
                cy += pt.y * weight;
                totalWeight += weight;
            }
            cx /= totalWeight;
            cy /= totalWeight;
        } while (Math.abs(cx - centroidx) > 0.5
                || Math.abs(cy - centroidy) > 0.5);// Probably this condition
                                                    // needs to change

        return new Point(cx, cy);
    }

    private static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        x1 -= x2;
        y1 -= y2;
        return Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1);
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix the bug, also if there exitis any better way to calculate `Geometric median` of some 2D points, write here. Thank you.

Comment: Best is to first find the exact spot of the problem and the state of the program at that time. Consider either using a debugger or sprinkle your code with println statements to check the state of the variables at key spots.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: For the points `(0,1), (2,5), (3,1), (4,0)`, my program prints `GeometricMedian= {2.4373634, 1.3966105}`. For these points it works but let say i have some other points `(-3,0), (-1,5), (0,10), (10,0), (50,0)`, program goes to an infinite loop. The problem is with the `while` condition. This condition needs to be updated depending upon the input points. But don't know how!

Comment: *again* first you need to debug your program. I think you're coming to stackoverflow prematurely, in that you must do your due diligence first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need two loops.  You only need the loop over all the points.  What is the reason for the other one, in your view?

Comment: If i remove the outer loop, which is `do-while`, the `centroid` becomes `Geometric median` for all input points. However `Geometric median` is not necessary equal to `centroid`. But once i put `do-while` loop, i am unable to put the correct condition to stop my `while` loop. This is why my outer `do-while` loop goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to iterate certain number of times. This similar to K-Means method where it either converges to a specific threshold or stops after a predefined number of iterations.