# find the center point of coordinate 2d array c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, center

Is there a formula to average all the x, y coordinates and find the location in the dead center of them.

I have 100x100 squares and inside them are large clumps of 1x1 red and black points, I want to determine out of the red points which one is in the middle.

I looked into line of best fit formulas but I am not sure if this is what I need.

Sometimes all the red will be on one side, or the other side. I want to essentially draw a line then find the center point of that line, or just find the center point of the red squares only. based on the 100x100 grid.

Comment: Do you want the `Median` or the `Mean`? What if the calculated centre point doesn't lay with one of the red points?

Comment: its float so it does not matter, or it can be rounded.  I would assume the mean or median would both be ok

Comment: No, I mean if you have two red points (-10, 0) and (10, 0), the centre point is (0, 0), but obviously there are no red points at (0,0), so what happens?

Comment: The average of a set of numbers does not necessarily exist in that set of numbers. The average (mean) of {1, 3, 8} is 6, but the *median* is 3.  *Edit: And @ChrisSinclair beats me to it by 11 seconds.*

Comment: @Bobson Yeah, but you said it better.

Comment: median could avoid potential problems then.  but how to formulate that?

Comment: It's not easy.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median.

Comment: Actually, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162273/calculating-geometric-median-of-2d-points - it's Java, but you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: Another quick and dirty option might be to calculate the average/mean, then just find the point closest to it. Depending on what your application is, it could be "good enough"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
List<Point> dots = new List<Point>();
int totalX = 0, totalY = 0;
foreach (Point p in dots)
{
    totalX += p.X;
    totalY += p.Y;
}
int centerX = totalX / dots.Count;
int centerY = totalY / dots.Count;
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply average separately the x coordinates and the y coordinates, the result will be the coordinates of the "center".

Comment: I am poor at math. Would I need to do  itr = 0; itr++; {x += x[itr]; y += y[itr]; x, y = x / x.count(), y / y.count();} 

?

Comment: Given you're using C#, not C++, it'd be something like: `new Point(points.Average(p => p.X), points.Average(p => p.Y));`.  Assuming `points` is a list of `Point` objects, and a `Point` has `X` and `Y`.  If you have an array of int arrays, it'd be `var X = points.Average(p => p[0]); var Y = points.Average(p => p[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

What if there are two or more subsets of red points ? Do you want the black point inside them?

Otherwis, if I understood your question, just give a weight of 1 to red points and 0 to blacks. Then do the weighted mean on X and Y coordinate

Comment: In Latex :  x = \sum x_i*w_i / \sum w_i. Same thing for y but with y_i. x_i and y_i are the ith point coordinates. w_i is 1 if it's red or 0 if not